# Regular Expression tag input autocomplete

Tags: regex

I'm having problems with function check validate product tags using Regular Expression. I want to get value 1,2,3 (no "," at the end. Example: 1,2,3 or 1,2,3,44,5). Below is my code.

```
$pat = '/^[0-9]+[,].$/';
if(preg_match($pat, $str))
{
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
```

Result:

- 1,2,3 -> return False. (need return TRUE)
- 1,2,3, -> return false.
- 1,2, -> return false
- 1 -> return false (need return TRUE)

so only 1,2 -> return true

(bad english please help me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex to validate a comma separated digit string,

```
^\d++(,\d++)*+$
```

This   also allows a single number.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY8tL9/2)

OR

```
^\d++(,\d++)++$
```

This won't allow a single number(without comma).

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY8tL9/3)

Added a `+` after every `+` and `*` because it would avoid [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) .

Comment: That someone may or may not be me @Jongware. Read more: [Explosive Quantifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html), [ReDoS - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS).

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*,$)(?>\d+,?)+$
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/83

Comment: Fails fast, good for when the input string is short, but has the problem with backtracking. Change the second group to `(?>)`.